# algorithm to determine complexity of algorithms?

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity

Given a decision problem X, can there exist an algorithm A which, given any algorithm B which solves X in finitely many steps, determines whether B runs in polynomial time? If such an A exists, when is it possible for A to run in polynomial time?

Comment: I don't think this qualifies as a soft question.  I'll remove the tag if no one objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some decision problems $X$, the answer to your question is affirmative, for the trivial reason that $X$ admits no polynomial-time solution, so $A$ can be the algorithm that always says "no".  But for more reasonable problems $X$, there cannot be any such $A$.

Consider a problem $X$ for which there is a polynomial-time algorithm $Q$ that decides $X$.  I claim that, if there were an $A$ as in your question, we could use it to decide the halting problem.  To see this, consider any instance of the halting problem, say Turing machine $M$ on input $z$.  Let $B$ be the following algorithm for solving the problem $X$.  On any input $x$, first use $Q$ to figure out the answer, but, instead of outputting the answer immediately, do two tasks in parallel: (1) count from 1 to $2^n$, where $n$ is the length of $x$, and (2) run $M$ on input $z$.  As soon as either of these tasks is finished, output the answer that $Q$ gave.  If machine $M$ on input $z$ doesn't halt, then task (2) will never be completed, so $B$ will produce an output only after exponential time $2^n$.  But if $M$ on $z$ halts after $s$ steps, then $B$ will produce its output after a polynomial number of steps, essentially the time needed by $Q$ plus (a constant overhead factor times) $s$.  So $B$ takes polynomial time iff $M$ on $z$ halts.

Now the program for $B$ can be effectively computed from that of $M$ and $z$.  So by producing $B$ and then applying the assumed algorithm $A$ to it, we could decide the halting problem.  Since the halting problem is known to be undecidable, it follows that there cannot be such an $A$.